# With Firefox, NVDA reads "Not selected" for table columns when tabindex is specified

Tags: html, firefox, html-table, nvda

Consider the below HTML code :

```html
<body>
<div valign="top">
    <table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse; empty-cells: show; width: 100%; overflow: auto hidden; height: auto;" >
        <caption style="padding: 9px 16px;box-sizing:border-box;text-align:center;">Sales</caption>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th tabindex="0">Person</th>
                <th>Coffee</th>
                <th>Tea</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th tabindex="0">ABC</th>
                <td>5 cups</td>
                <td>0 cups</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>XYZ</th>
                <td>1 cups</td>
                <td>2 cups</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

When I try to read the table using screen reader, for table headers with tabindex specified, "Person" & "ABC", NVDA reads it as below :

> Person  column header  not selected  row 1  column 1
>
> Coffee  column header  column 2
>
> Person  column header  not selected  column 1
>
> ABC  row header  not selected  row 2  Person  column 1

**Is this a correct behavior to announce "not selected" for table cells which has tabindex specified.**
NVDA output for the same html works fine with Chrome.

**Is there any way to avoid "not selected".**

NVDA Version : 2021.2
Firefox Version : 93.0 (64-bit)

Thanks,

Ajay

Comment: Is there any reason you're giving tabindex to the th?

Comment: This is because of a requirement. We need to make it focusable.

Comment: You giving role="presentation" for the table and try

Comment: That *is* strange.  I inspected the accessibility properties of the table headers in both firefox and chrome and they have similar properties.  Nothing to indicate that "not selected" should be read.  I would recommend reporting a bug to NVDA.  I searched the existing bugs and didn't see a "not selected" bug related to tables.  https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues

Comment: @lost_in_magento: Role as "presentation" removes the semantics of the native HTML element. I won't be able to use it in this case..

Comment: @slugolicious : Yeah true, the issue comes for any table cell which has tabindex specified( not specific to table headers only ). I have already raised an issue with Firefox : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1737251 . Would yo recommend me to raise the same issue with NVDA as well. Thanks.

Comment: I think it's an NVDA issue, not a firefox issue.  As mentioned in my previous comment, I inspected the accessibility properties in both firefox and chrome and both looked good.  That means NVDA is causing the problem even though it sounds ok in chrome.